# Постобработка текста на питоне

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, nlp

я пишу генератор гороскопов, с генерацией все хорошо, моя нейронная сеть справляется прекрасно, но есть нюанс)
Изначально встал вопрос о том, какие данные отдавать нейросети на обучение:

- первой идеей было заменить слово знака зодиака на blank и менять его перед выводом пользователю на нужный знак зодиака, но встроить это слово в контекст у меня не вышло, поэтому от этого варианта я отказался
- при генерации ответа нейросети была идея добавить 11 знаков в бэдвордс, чтобы понизить их веса, но я использую нейросеть, которой давали данные с опечатками, которые она мне и выплевывает (я только дообучил модель на своих данных)
- следующая мысль была оставить знаки зодиака и не привязываться к ним, если в тексте был ненужный знак зодиака, я просто его заменял на нужный, с помощью pymorphy2 я доставал нужную форму слова (падеж,число...) и ставил новое слово в эту форму, но есть одна глобальная проблема - это слова в контексте, они не меняются, хотя, хотелось бы, союзы или местоимения остаются неизменными, есть ли  что-нибудь для постобработки в подобных случаях?
  Сервисы типа Спеллер от Яндекса или Ворд не справляются, к сожалению.
  Пару примеров скинул ниже:

"...Даже если обычно Рак предпочитает соглашаться со своим избранником..."

#########

"...Даже если обычно Овна предпочитает соглашаться со своим избранником..."

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

"...Скорпион способен на проявление максимально ярких чувств!..."

#########

"...Дева способен на проявление максимально ярких чувств!..."